# Difference between creating Flutter Project using Kotlin lang. and Java lang.?

Tags: flutter

When you create a flutter project you can specify one of two programming languages for Android: Kotlin and Java.

```
flutter create -i swift -a kotlin project.name.app
```

or

```
flutter create -i swift -a java project.name.app
```

What is the difference or is there any differences between creating Flutter project which translates, so to speak, to Kotlin or Java? Advantages, disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not planning on writing any native, non-Dart code it shouldn't matter. If you are writing native code there's no performance benefits to using Java vs Kotlin, so it's really up to your personal preferences. Basically, just use the language that you're most comfortable with :-)